# listing items in listbox from ms access database

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am trying to list items in a MS Access database into a listbox in C# Windows Form.
In the table I have 5 fields including ID.
The goal is to get field name and field created to the listbox by way of the type and userID fields. However, when I try nothing is displayed, but if I put

```
 try
 {
     Conn.Open();
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     ds.Tables.Add(dt);
     //  textBox3.Text = databaseHandler.UserId.ToString();
     OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from COLLVAULT_LISTS WHERE list_type='" + textBox2.Text + "' AND  user_id=4", Conn);
     da.Fill(dt);

     foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)
     {
         lvlist.Items.Add(myRow["name"].ToString());
         //     lvlist.Items[lvlist.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(myRow[3].ToString());    
     }
     Conn.Close();
 }
 catch
 {

 }
```

Then I get the lists. But since that id can be different, I need to use the value in `textBox3` instead of 4 which is what I have done here below

```
try
{
    Conn.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    //  textBox3.Text = databaseHandler.UserId.ToString();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from COLLVAULT_LISTS WHERE list_type='" + textBox2.Text + "' AND  user_id='" + textBox3.Text + "'", Conn);
    da.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow myRow in dt.Rows)
    {
        lvlist.Items.Add(myRow["name"].ToString());//qty
        //     lvlist.Items[lvlist.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(myRow[3].ToString());//year

    }
    Conn.Close();
}
catch
{

}
```

However, again nothing is shown. So if anyone has any ideas please pass them to me.

Comment: WHY do you wrap code in try-statements that have empty catch-statements? You'll quash every exception that might tell you what's actually going wrong.

Comment: Did you debug the code? Does it execute the for loop?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - I did debug it after adding in the exception for the catch and got a error of data type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: @J.Steen if was my fault on that I just didn't add it in right away

Comment: Did you figure out the solution?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Not yet I haven't I am still trying different things. when I debug the query has thecorrect information so maybe something with how I have it showing into the listbox perhaps?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have it figured out. I had to change the user_id field in the db to a shorttext field and it worked but I am on the right track of the cause now and should be able to change it back to number and still get it to work.

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.  It would certainly fix the problem you are having, too.